# Vert.x Kotlin Type Mismatch required Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>> found (Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>>) -> Unit

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, java-interop

The following is a method rewritten in Kotlin from Java:

```
fun publishMessageSource(
        name: String,
        address: String,
        completionHandler: Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>>
) {
    val record = MessageSource.createRecord(name, address)
    publish(record, completionHandler)
}
```

However, when I call it as follows:

```
publishMessageSource("market-data", ADDRESS, { record: Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>> ->
            if (!record.succeeded()) {
                record.cause().printStackTrace()
            }
            println("Market-Data service published : ${record.succeeded()}")
        })
```

I get the error `Type Mismatch required Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>> found (Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>>) -> Unit`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda should take the parameter that the single method of the `Handler` interface takes, which is `AsyncResult<Unit>` in this case. Your lambda *is* the `Handler`, so it doesn't take the `Handler` as a parameter.

I think you'll also need an explicit call to the SAM constructor here, since your function is written in Kotlin, that would look something like this:

```
publishMessageSource("market-data", ADDRESS, Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>> { record: AsyncResult<Unit>  ->
    ...
})
```

This creates a `Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>>` with a lambda representing its single method.

Finally, you can omit the type inside the lambda to be less redundant:

```
publishMessageSource("market-data", ADDRESS, Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>> { record ->
    ...
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Especially useful info about the SAM constructor. That's what I was trying to achieve with specifying the type of `record` in the lambda. I'll go re-read the stuff on SAM.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit of a weird use case for it. By default SAM conversion works for Java interfaces and Java methods that take those interfaces by just writing down a lambda, but explicitly writing the name of the interface before the lambda makes it available in this case too, when the function is in Kotlin. Now that I think of it, you could make your function take a proper Kotlin function and then create the Handler inside it to make this neater.

Comment: Good suggestion: not too sure why I didn't think of that. I've gone for `resultHandler: (AsyncResult<Unit>) -> Unit` and pass that on as a `Handler<AsyncResult<Unit>>(resultHandler)`. Allows me to use the last parameter is a lambda outside of the brackets notation too. I couldn't do that when calling the SAM constructor - is that one of its side effects?

Comment: Yes, indeed, you can do that with SAM conversion, but not with an explicit SAM constructor.